# Why if I typecast String? to Any, Xcode gives off warning, but not with AnyObject?

Tags: swift, option-type, any, anyobject

This code gives warning "Expression implicitly coerced from 'String?' to Any."

```
let email : String?;
let password : String?;
let dict = ["email": email, "password": password] as [String: Any];
```

But this code does not.

```
let email : String?;
let password : String?;
let dict = ["email": email, "password": password] as [String: AnyObject];
```

Why? And how can I make that `Any` does not bother me with warning about optionals like `AnyObject`?

EDIT:

This code also does not gives away warning:

```
let email : String;
let password : String;
let dict = ["email": email, "password": password] as [String: Any];
```

But I need to be able to incorporate both object and optionality in this case. It seems the warning only appears if the variable type is both object *and* optional.

Comment: `Any` can represent an instance of any type at all, including function types and optional types & `AnyObject` can represent an instance of any class type. So, in your case `String` Object is `Class` Object thats way its not giving warning.

Comment: @Rocky I have updated the question.

Comment: An optional dictionary value is nonsense. According to the dictionary definition `nil` is returned if the key does not exist. So if you want a `nil` value omit the key. And remove the trailing semicolons. They are pointless in Swift.

Comment: @vadian optional dictionary value is indeed nonsense. The problem is those optionals come from parameters. By using typecast to `as [String: AnyObject]`, any nil value is automatically not included in the final dictionary. And yes semicolons are pointless. But I switch back and forth between Obj C and Swift project, and rather than I kept getting frustrated because I forgot to put semicolons when working with Obj C, I prefer to put extra semicolons in Swift, just so that I do not lose my reflex to add semicolons after statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Swift Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html) you are expected to get a warning when casting optional to Any (see note at the bottom of the page). You can get rid of warning by casting optional value to `Any` as shown below.

```
let email : String?;
let password : String?;
let dict = ["email": email as Any, "password": password as Any] as [String: Any];
```

Comment: But that means I need to add `as Any` to every value. I was just found a workaround though, that is by cast it to `[String: AnyObject]` and then cast it to `[String: Any]`. Why is this possible?

Comment: `Any` can by anything, `AnyObject` some object of a class, but for example it cannot be function type. You can use `Any` instea of `AnyObject`, `String`, etc.so your type casting is valid. And you are probably working with normal objects so using `AnyObject` is a good solution.